# PHPExcel - getHighestDataColumn causes server error

Tags: php, phpexcel

I am using PHP Excel 1.8.0. If I use the below code, I get the highest column as "WTZ".

```
try {
    $fileType  = PHPExcel_IOFactory::identify($filePath);
    $objReader = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createReader($fileType);
    $objReader->setReadDataOnly(true);
    $objPHPExcel = $objReader->load($filePath);
} 
catch(Exception $e) {
    die( 'Error loading excel file' . $e->getMessage() );
}
$objPHPExcel->setActiveSheetIndex(0);
$activeSheet      = $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet();
$highestColumn    = $activeSheet->getHighestColumn();
$highestColumnNum = (int) PHPExcel_Cell::columnIndexFromString($highestColumn);
```

Data content is only till 6th column. So, I tried  "getHighestDataColumn()"  instead of, "getHighestColumn()". Then, I noticed that it takes longer than usual to read the file, and stops after causing a "500 Internal Server". I have debugged the PHP script, and am sure that this is the line that causes server error. Any workaround is appreciated.

Comment: check the server's error log for details about the 500.

Comment: Thanks. It was a memory related error. After I set it to 512 MB, the error is gone. But, my question is how can I get the highest column value? Now, even though, data is only till 9th column, getHighestDataColumn() returns 16094.